# Does jQuery(element) select each element one-by-one or all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I was tasked with getting all words in a paragraph and making each word switch to a random color once per second.

I wrote this, thinking it would make all words switch to the SAME random color, under the assumption that `$('span')` finds all span elements and does the same thing on all of them at once.

However, this code switches each word to a **different** random color, as if it's running a different instance of `makeHexColor` on each `span`. I'm very confused, as I thought, what would happen was that inside `setInterval`, `makeHexColor` would first evaluate to a random string and then that one particular string would be attached to the color attribute of all spans.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = $('p').text().split(' ');
  
  $('p').empty();  
  words.forEach(function(word) {
    $('p').append($('<span>').text(word + ' '));
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $('span').css('color', makeHexColor);
  }, 1000);
})

var makeHexColor = function() {
  var hex = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  var color = '#';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    color += hex[random];
  }
  
  return color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$('span').css`... is actually transpiled to a loop by jQuery and for each iteration it is calling the `makeHexColor` function.

If you would like to have all words in the same color update your `setInterval` to:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var color = makeHexColor();
    $('span').css('color', color) 
},1000)
```

Comment: Ah ok, so under the hood, jQuery will loop through each span element and call a new instance of makeHexColor on each one? (sidenote: am I using the word "instance" correctly here?)

Comment: If you continue to use it as before - Yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that does what you ask.

https://jsfiddle.net/dka1qojh/

Essentially, just create a `hexValue` variable to update on an interval and keep the original code. I hope this helps.